# app engine python tutorial error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do the python tutorial here
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld.html

(I have python 2.5 installed)

After creating the python and yaml files I used the app engine launcher to run the code. Then I checked localhost:8080 and received the following error:

```
<class 'google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError'>   Python 2.5: C:\Python25\pythonw.exe
Sat Apr 02 17:15:11 2011
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _HandleRequest(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x02CF0D50>)
 3837         config, explicit_matcher = LoadAppConfig(root_path, self.module_dict,
 3838                                                  cache=self.config_cache,
 3839                                                  static_caching=static_caching)
 3840         if config.api_version != API_VERSION:
 3841           logging.error(
static_caching = True
 C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in LoadAppConfig(root_path=r'C:\Users\Uri\Dropbox\memory-graph\memory-graph', module_dict={'codecs': <module 'codecs' from 'C:\Python25\lib\codecs.pyc'>, 'email': <module 'email' from 'C:\Python25\lib\email\__init__.pyc'>, 'email.Charset': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A330>, 'email.Encoders': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A350>, 'email.Errors': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A370>, 'email.FeedParser': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A310>, 'email.Generator': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A390>, 'email.Header': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A3D0>, 'email.Iterators': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A3B0>, 'email.MIMEAudio': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x0254A490>, ...}, cache=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigCache object at 0x0271C870>, static_caching=True, read_app_config=<function ReadAppConfig at 0x0271F230>, create_matcher=<function CreateURLMatcherFromMaps at 0x0271F270>)
 4164         pass
 4165 
 4166   raise AppConfigNotFoundError
 4167 
 4168 
global AppConfigNotFoundError = <class 'google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError'>
<class 'google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError'>:
```

any ideas?

Comment: Weird. I just reinstalled it and now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working - it was just complaining because it couldn't find its own configuration file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AppEngine SDK is complaining because it can't find its own configuration file.   Try reinstalling using the MSI provided on the Google AppEngine site.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I solved this problem by adding the path to where the "app.yaml" file is located under the "Arguments" tab of the "Debug Configurations" dialog:

[image]