# Trouble with Google App Engine Python Tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have looked at the question [app engine python tutorial error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524687/app-engine-python-tutorial-error). It does not answer my question so this is not a duplicate question :)

I am following the Google App Engine Python tutorial.  I am running into trouble when I attempt to run the example in part 4 "Using the Users Service".  When I follow the instructions I get this error:

```
2015-02-06 17:56:22 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\plankton\\google_app_eng\\helloworld\\helloworld']"
INFO     2015-02-06 17:56:26,164 devappserver2.py:745] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-02-06 17:56:26,203 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:52731
INFO     2015-02-06 17:56:26,210 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-02-06 17:56:26,213 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-02-07 01:57:04,624 wsgi.py:263] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 302, in _LoadHandler

    raise err

ImportError: <module 'main' from 'C:\Users\plankton\google_app_eng\helloworld\helloworld\main.pyc'> has no attribute app

INFO     2015-02-06 17:57:04,651 module.py:718] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Here is a link to the part of the tutorial that I am having trouble with: [Using the Users Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers)
Can anyone out there help me out?

Thanks!

Update: Thanks Alex! I think I get your point.

```
$ diff main.py main.py.500err
44c44
< app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
---
> application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I lied.  I did not follow the tutorial exactly!  When I created my `helloworld` from the first part of the tutorial I used the "Google App Engine Launcher" to create the project instead of creating the files externally from the Launcher and creating the project by selecting the `File menu, Add Existing Application...`, then selecting the `helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever exactly you did, your `main.py` does **not** have a global object named `app`, as it should have had you followed the tutorial.

Can you show us the part of your `main.py` you **thought** would make a global object (a WSGI app) called `app`?  Then we can try and help explain why that part didn't.  Or did you just completely ignore that not-so-tiny aspect?-)

If your `app.yaml`'s `handlers:` section says `script:` followed by `main.app`, this means those URLs will be handled by a WSGI application object called `app`, built and housed in your `main.py` (that's with the `python27` value for `runtime:`, which I bet is what you're using).

If you tell the system (by entries in `app.yaml`) to look for name `app` in `main`, and there is no such global name there, guess what you get...?

A-yup, **exactly** an error message `<module 'main' from [snip] > has no attribute app` -- because your "module `main`", guess what!, **has no attribute `app`**!  So what about fixing that issue, which the error message is so totally clear about?-)